# Getting the sum and max from a list using stream

Tags: java, sum, max, grouping, java-stream

Hi I have a List where the data looks like this

```
[{"month":"April","day":"Friday","count":5},

{"month":"April","day":"Monday","count":6},

{"month":"April","day":"Saturday","count":2},

{"month":"April","day":"Sunday","count":1},

{"month":"April","day":"Thursday","count":7},

{"month":"April","day":"Tuesday","count":8},

{"month":"April","day":"Wednesday","count":10},

{"month":"March","day":"Friday","count":3},

{"month":"March","day":"Monday","count":2},

{"month":"March","day":"Saturday","count":15},

{"month":"March","day":"Sunday","count":11},

{"month":"March","day":"Thursday","count":4},

{"month":"March","day":"Tuesday","count":20},

{"month":"March","day":"Wednesday","count":7},

{"month":"May","day":"Friday","count":2},

{"month":"May","day":"Monday","count":0},

{"month":"May","day":"Saturday","count":7},

{"month":"May","day":"Sunday","count":4},

{"month":"May","day":"Thursday","count":8},

{"month":"May","day":"Tuesday","count":3},

{"month":"May","day":"Wednesday","count":6}]
```

My object class is

```
String month;
String day;
Integer count;
```

What I want to get by using stream is sum of count grouped by month and the day with max count for that month.

so end result will look something like

April, Wednesday, 39
March, Tuesday, 62
May, Thursday , 30

I have been trying to use stream and grouping by but no luck. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT**

```
 Map<String, Integer> totalMap = transactions.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MonthlyTransaction::getMonth, Collectors.summingInt(MonthlyTransaction::getCount)));
     Map<String, String> maxMap = transactions.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MonthlyTransaction::getMonth)).values().stream().toMap(Object::getDay, Collextions.max(Object::getCount);
```

obviously the maxMap method is wrong but I do not know how to write it.

Comment: Could you show some of your tries?

Comment: I managed to get the sum but i am struggling to  map the day with the max count for the month. below is the code that i have for now.

transactions.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Object::getMonth, Collectors.summingInt(Object::getCount)));

Comment: Is Month and Day unique within your list? If I take a look at the expected result, where are the other days for April? I don't understand the business case.

Comment: Month and day are unique yes. In the expected result

 April has a total of 39 count and Wednesday had the maximum count

Comment: Please post code for fill data into List variable...

Comment: Edited to show the code i have. that is all i got.

Comment: Ok, I don't know what data structure you use for store data. Are you using a List of arrays and inside these arrays you have 3 maps?

Comment: I use list. But at the end it will be converted to a json

Comment: @Ankit can you narrow you input and show the actual classes that you have?

Comment: have a working solution now. Thanks for looking at this . Please feel free to suggest if the solution can be optimized

Comment: @Ankit we can't really help you unless you provide the information about how your classes are constructed and what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: @Eugene .. Really sorry ..But that is all i had in my code. I am not an expert at this and i still do not know what more you were asking for. I gave the exact data , the expected result and the pojo structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find both the sum of counts per month and the day with the max count per month in a single pass, I think you need a custom collector.

First, let's create a holder class where to store the results:

```
public class Statistics {

    private final String dayWithMaxCount;

    private final long totalCount;

    public Statistics(String dayWithMaxCount, long totalCount) {
        this.dayWithMaxCount = dayWithMaxCount;
        this.totalCount = totalCount;
    }

    // TODO getters and toString
}
```

Then, create this method, which returns a collector that accumulates both the sum of counts and the max count, along with the day in which that max was found:

```
public static Collector<MonthlyTransaction, ?, Statistics> withStatistics() {
    class Acc {
        long sum = 0;
        long maxCount = Long.MIN_VALUE;
        String dayWithMaxCount;

        void accumulate(MonthlyTransaction transaction) {
            sum += transaction.getCount();
            if (transaction.getCount() > maxCount) {
                maxCount = transaction.getCount();
                dayWithMaxCount = transaction.getDay();
            }
        }

        Acc merge(Acc another) {
            sum += another.sum;
            if (another.maxCount > maxCount) {
                maxCount = another.maxCount;
                dayWithMaxCount = another.dayWithMaxCount;
            }
            return this;
        }

        Statistics finish() {
            return new Statistics(dayWithMaxCount, sum);
        }
    }
    return Collector.of(Acc::new, Acc::accumulate, Acc::merge, Acc::finish);
}
```

This uses the local class `Acc` to accumulate and merge partial results. The `finish` method returns an instance of the `Statistics` class, which holds the final results. At the end, I'm using [`Collector.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...-) to create a collector based on the methods of the `Acc` class.

Finally, you can use the method and class defined above as follows:

```
Map<String, Statistics> statisticsByMonth = transactions.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MonthlyTransaction::getMonth, withStatistics()));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is awesome. Did not occur to me i could write a custom collector method (something new learned). This worked perfectly !!

Answer (score 0):

did this in 2 steps instead of trying to write 1 stream to achieve the result

```
//First get the total of counts grouping by month
Map<String, Integer> totalMap = transactions.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MonthlyTransaction::getMonth, Collectors.summingInt(MonthlyTransaction::getCount)));

List<MonthlyTransaction> finalStat = new ArrayList<>();

//iterate over the total count map
totalMap.entrySet().stream().forEach(entry -> {
//Using the Stream filter to mimic a group by 
MonthlyTransaction maxStat = transactions.stream()
    .filter(t -> t.getMonth().equals(entry.getKey()))
        //getting the item with the max count for the month
       .max(Comparator.comparing(MonthlyTransaction::getCount)).get();

//Setting the count to the total value from the map as the max count value is not a requirement.
maxStat.setCount(entry.getValue());

//add the item to the list
finalStat.add(maxStat);
});
```

This may not be the best approach to the problem but this gives me the exact result. Thanks to everyone who had a look at it and tried to help.